# Using VBA to duplicate a Word table row without using Copy/Paste

Tags: vba, delphi, ms-word

I am using VBA with Delphi to populate a Word Table.  My logic relies on Selection Copy and Paste, and this is problematic because of possible interaction with other running programs.
I would like to rewrite so it does not rely on Copy/Paste.

Below is a screenshot of the Word doc.  The table I need to populate is the "Order Details" table.

[image: Table Template]

Below is the code I am using. The basic steps:

- Find "@DTL_QTY" tag.
- Select the row, Copy/Paste that row (so now we have two row with the tags).
- Update each tag in the selected row.
- Repeat for additional rows.
- After all rows are processed, delete the last "Template" row.

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    i: Integer;
    MSWord: Variant;
begin
    MSWord := CreateOleObject('word.application');
    MSWord.WordBasic.FileOpen('c:\temp\invoice1.dot');
    for i := 1 to 3 do begin
        MSWord.Selection.WholeStory;
        MSWord.WordBasic.EditFind('@DTL_QTY');
        MSWord.WordBasic.TableSelectRow;
        MSWord.Selection.Range.Copy;
        MSWord.Selection.Range.Paste;
        MSWord.Selection.WholeStory;

        MSWord.WordBasic.EditFind('@DTL_QTY');
        MSWord.WordBasic.TableSelectRow;
        MSWord.WordBasic.EditReplace('@DTL_QTY', inttostr(i), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        MSWord.WordBasic.TableSelectRow;
        MSWord.WordBasic.EditReplace('@DTL_DESC','Desc: ' + inttostr(i), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        end;

    { finally, get rid of the row used as a template }
    MSWord.WordBasic.EditSelectAll;
    MSWord.WordBasic.EditFind('@DTL_QTY');
    MSWord.WordBasic.TableSelectRow;
    { Delete the last line, which was our template }
    MSWord.Selection.Range.Cut;

    MSWord.WordBasic.AppShow;
    ShowMessage('Review Doc');
    MSWord.Quit(False, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
end;
```

Below is a screenshot of the results:

[image: Results Table]

Comment: There's no VBA here. This is Delphi code using Word COM automation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - thanks for pointing it out.  I did not know the difference between COM and VBA.  This is legacy code I have been tasked to change.  Would it be possible to modify the COM code to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

- Here comes Word VBA code. You could revised it for delphi.
- Use `InsertRowsAbove` to insert TWO rows, then the code don't have to remove an extra row at the end.
- Populate three rows with the expected data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRows()
    Dim i As Long, oTab As Table
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "@DTL_QTY"
        If .Execute Then
            If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
                ' Select the row, it is not necessary in Word VBA
                Selection.Rows(1).Select
                ' Insert two 2 rows above
                Selection.InsertRowsAbove 2
                ' Get the table object
                Set oTab = Selection.Tables(1)
                For i = 1 To 3
                    oTab.Cell(i + 1, 1).Range.Text = CStr(i)
                    oTab.Cell(i + 1, 2).Range.Text = "Desc: " & CStr(i)
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]